# Ranorex - NeoLoad Integration What is transactionName?

Tags: c#, ranorex, neoload

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/combine-ranorex-and-neoload-tests/).

I have installed `NeoLoad` and have created the user code `Send Timing Values` as seen in the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I am unsure about the argument `transactionName`. The tutorial says *"We recommend using the current page as a transaction name in the Ranorex action table"*, yet when I put the URL of the page in the argument the test errors.

Any help is appreciated.